# Toggling ngIf with separate components using service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

So I'm trying to toggle an element in a separate component, while firing the function to change the boolean value from the ionic tabs component so far I have this.

//App.module.ts - Cut down for the sake of brevity

```
import { AppGlobals } from './globals';

@NgModule({
    providers: [AppGlobals]
})
```

//Globals.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable() 
export class AppGlobals {
  // use this property for property binding
  public showSearch:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  setShowSearch(search){
      this.showSearch.next(search);
      console.log(search);
  }
}
```

// Tabs.ts

```
import { AppGlobals } from '../../app/globals';

constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {
     this._appGlobals.showSearch.subscribe(value => this.search = value);
}

toggleSearch() {
    this.search = !this.search;
    console.log(this.search);
}
```

//Tabs.html

```
(ionSelect)="toggleSearch();"
```

//This is on some HTML within the the separate component

```
<div *ngIf="search" [ngClass]="{'slideInRight':showSearch, 'fadeOut':!showSearch}" class="search-filters animated">
```

However this doesn't appear to be working, I'm toggling the value however the global "showSearch" seems to stay the same. What is the correct way of achieving the toggle of the element across the two components?

Any help at all is very appreciated.

Comment: @VladuIonut Doesn't appear to make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Tabs.ts` will emit an event when `toggleSearch()` method call

```
toggleSearch() {
    this.search = !this.search;
    console.log(this.search);
    this._appGlobals.showSearch.next(this.search);
}
```

in another component

```
import { AppGlobals } from 'path/to/app/globals';
@Component({...})
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {

    showSearch: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._appGlobals.showSearch.subscribe(value => this.showSearch = value);
    }

}
```

SubComponent template

```
<div *ngIf="showSearch">content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has almost worked. It seems now the element is showing but instantly hiding again. Any ideas? I've added the rest of the html to my question.

Comment: Scratch that, I fixed it, seems I needed to make it all search in the html rather than showSearch. Thank you very much for your help.